# How to compare the data of two files (.xml and .html) using perl(regex)?

Tags: regex, perl

I tried using regex by using foreach loop for .xml files as there are many .xml files and only one .html file. I opened, read and closed the directory. But when it comes to searching for a particular pattern in both the files, the code doesn't enter the while/if loop.

xml data:            #pattern in xml format

```
<gname>abc</gname>
<pname>xyz</pname>
```

html data:             #pattern in html format

```
<p>ABC</p>
<p><i>xyz</i></p>
```

Here, I need to match `abc` and `xyz` in both xml and html file (case sensitive).

```
open( F2, "<F2>" );
my $xml_list1 = "(.*)\.html";
```

here the data enclosed inside the parentheses also appears when printed. I want say the file name is `abc.html` so i want to keep "`abc`" as interchangeable, so that i dont need to write/modify the code if any filename other than `abc.html` occurs.

```
close F2;
#print $xml_list1."\n";

foreach my $f (@filenames) {
    #print $f."\n";
    open( F1, "<F1>" );
    my $data = join( "", <F1> );
    close F1;
    my $filename = substr( $f, 0, index( $f, '.' ) );
    my $xml_list = $filename . ".xml";

    while ( $xml_list =~ m//ig ) {
        ...;
    }
}
```

the code doesn't enter the while/if loop, seems that it finds some error in reading the filename `$xml_list`.

I want to match both the data without the use of parsers.

Can someone please help me to out.

UPDATE:
CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;

my $path1=getcwd;

opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
my @out = grep(/.(xml)$/,readdir(INP));
my @out1 = grep(/.(html)$/,readdir(INP));
close INP;

foreach my $final(@out)
{
 my $filetobecopied = "Input\/".$final;
 my $newfile = $final;
 copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
}

foreach my $final1(@out1)
{
 my $filetobecopied1 = "Input\/".$final1;
 my $newfile1 = $final1;
 copy($filetobecopied1, $newfile1) or die "File cannot be copied.";
}

opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
my @files = grep /(.*?)\.(xml)$/,(readdir DIR);
my @files1 = grep /(.*?)\.(html)$/,(readdir DIR);
closedir DIR;

open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
print F6 "FileName\tError Instance\tOutput\n";

# open(F2,"<F2>");
# my $xml_list1="abc.html";
# my $data1=join("",<F1>);
# my $xml_list2=$xml_list1;

foreach my $f(@files)
 {
open(F1, "<$f") or die "Cannot open file: $files[0]";
my $data=join("", <F1>);
close F1;
my $xml_list=$data;
#print "$f\n";

open(F2, "<$f") or die "Cannot open file: $files[0]";
my $xml_listt="abc.html";
my $data1=join("", <F2>);
my $xml_list1=$data1;

print $xml_list1."\n";

while($xml_list=~m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
{
        my $full=$1;
        my $name=$2;
        #print F6 $f."\t".$full."\n";       
if($full=~m/(<givenNames>(\w+)<\/givenNames>(\n)?<familyName>(\w+)<\/familyName>(\n)?(.*?))/isg)
        {
        my $fg=$1;
        my $gname=$2;
        my $fname=$4;
        #print F6 $f."\t".$gname."\t".$fname."\n";
        }
     }
While($xml_list1=~m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)" SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/igs)        
    {
    my $hfull=$1;
    print F6 $f."\n";   #.$hfull."\n";
    }
close F2;
close F1;
}
foreach my $del(@files)
{
unlink $del;
}
```

Comment: I think the value of $xml_list will be the filename but not the content of the file and also filename can be                          my $xml_list = $filename . "\." . "xml"; . So you cannot able to match the pattern.

Comment: It's a little difficult to know exactly what your script is doing as you haven't included the whole thing, but you may benefit from reading more about opening files and directories. Try [Perl file IO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_files.htm) and [Perl directories](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_directories.htm).

Comment: Try to be clear what you want exactly and if you want to compare only data of both the files then already there is an answer for that in stackoverflow. Check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@flora : This is the final solution i am posting it . Here from xml files i have combined  with  and matched with data in the html . Now i am passing an argument to the program only one pattern that i want to check whether it matched with xml and html files . Like for example i have passed the argument "Kazumitsu Sugiura" to the program and now the program takes the value from  and  from xml and combines it as "Kazumitsu Sugiura" . This pattern will now check in the html file and if it matches then the filenames will be displayed as shown below :

**InputFile:**(sample.xml)

```
<creators> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="01"> 
<personName><givenNames>Kazumitsu</givenNames><familyName>Sugiura</familyName></personName>
</creator> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="02"> 
<personName><givenNames>Yoshinao</givenNames><familyName>Muro</familyName></personName>
</cre??ator> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="03"> 
<personName><givenNames>Masashi</givenNames><familyName>Akiyama</familyName></personName> 
</creator>
</creators>
```

**InputFile:**(test.xml)

```
<creators> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="01"> 
<personName><givenNames>Kazumitsu</givenNames><familyName>Sugiura</familyName></personName>
</creator> 
</creators>
```

**InputFile:**(test.html)

```
<P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA, Yoshinao Muro, and Masashi Akiyama</I></FONT></P>
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Cwd;
    use File::Copy;
    use File::Basename;

    my $path1=getcwd;
    my $PatternName = $ARGV[0];     

    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files = grep /(.*?)\.(xml)$/,(readdir DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files1 = grep /(.*?)\.(html)$/,(readdir DIR);        
    closedir DIR;

    #print @files1;

    open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
    print F6 "FileName\tMatchedString\tOutput\n";        

    foreach my $f (@files)
     {   

    open(F1, "<$path1\/$f") or die "Cannot open file: $f - $!";
    my $data=join("", <F1>);
    close F1;
    my $xml_list=$data;    
    #print $xml_list;
   foreach my $f1 (@files1)
    {
         my @fname=(); 
         my @hfull=();
        #print $f1 . "\n";
    open(F2, "<$path1\/$f1") or die "Cannot open file: $f1 - $!";
    my $data1=join("", <F2>);
    close F2;
    my $xml_list1=$data1;
    #print $xml_list1;
    while($xml_list =~ m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
       {
            my $full=$1;
            #print $full . "\n";
    if($full =~ m/(<givenNames>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/givenNames>\s*<familyName>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/familyName>\s*(.*?))/isg)
            { 
                my $var = "$2 $3";
              push(@fname,$var);
                 }

         }
    while($xml_list1 =~ m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)" SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/isg)        
        {
           push(@hfull,$4);
       }


    foreach my $a (@fname)
      {
         if($a =~ /$PatternName/i)
          {
        foreach my $b (@hfull)
           { 
              if($b =~ m/$PatternName/isg)
                 {     
                    print $PatternName . "\n";
                    my $line  = substr($b,index(lc($b),lc($PatternName)),length($PatternName));
                      print F6 "Matched $a($f)\->$line($f1)\n";
                      }      
               } 
            }   
         }      
      }     
    }
```

**Program Execution :**

perl filename.pl "Kazumitsu Sugiura"

**Output:**

```
Matched Kazumitsu Sugiura(sample.xml)->Kazumitsu SUGIURA(abc.html)
Matched Kazumitsu Sugiura(test.xml)->Kazumitsu SUGIURA(abc.html)
```

Comment: thanks Praveen..it goes into loop again and again and prints the  data multiple times and it shows an error saying $PatternName needs explicit package..How can we also show error when there is a mismatch found between xml and html file i.e Kazumitsu in xml and Kajumiju in html? In HTML file, I am trying to separate each author name and taking it as an individual string. ie it is like this <I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA,Yoshinao Muro,and Masashi Akiyama</I> I want Kazumitsu SUGIURA (newline) Yoshinao Muro(newline) Masashi Akiyama so that it just matches Kazumitsu SUGIURA(xml)with Kazumitsu SUGIURA (html)

Answer (score 0):

@flora: I have modified your program and also i have put the optimized solution for your program.

**Modified Code :(Modification to your program)**

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use Cwd;
    use File::Copy;
    use File::Basename;

    my $path1=getcwd;

    opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
    my @out = grep(/\.(xml)$/,readdir(INP));
    my @out1 = grep(/\.(html)$/,readdir(INP));
    close INP;

    foreach my $final(@out)
    {
     my $filetobecopied = "Input\/".$final;
     my $newfile = $final;
     copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    }

    foreach my $final1(@out1)
    {
     my $filetobecopied1 = "Input\/".$final1;
     my $newfile1 = $final1;
     copy($filetobecopied1, $newfile1) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    }

    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files = grep /(.*?)\.(xml)$/,(readdir DIR);
    my @files1 = grep /(.*?)\.(html)$/,(readdir DIR);
    closedir DIR;

    open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
    print F6 "FileName\tError Instance\tOutput\n";

    # open(F2,"<F2>");
    # my $xml_list1="abc.html";
    # my $data1=join("",<F1>);
    # my $xml_list2=$xml_list1;

    foreach my $f (@files)
     {    
    open(F1, "<$f") or die "Cannot open file: $f";
    my $data=join("", <F1>);
    close F1;
    my $xml_list=$data;    
    open(F2, "<$path1\/Input\/abc.html") or die "Cannot open file: abc.html - $!";
    my $data1=join("", <F2>);
    close F2;
    my $xml_list1=$data1;
    print $xml_list1."\n";

    while($xml_list =~ m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
    {
            my $full=$1;
            my $name=$2;
            #print F6 $f."\t".$full."\n";       
    if($full =~ m/(<givenNames>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/givenNames>\s*<familyName>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/familyName>\s*(.*?))/isg)
            {
            my $fg=$1;
            my $gname=$2;
            my $fname=$3;
            #print F6 $f."\t".$gname."\t".$fname."\n";
            }
         }
    while($xml_list1 =~ m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)" SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/isg)        
        {
        my $hfull= $1;
        print F6 $f."\n";   #.$hfull."\n";
        }

    }
    foreach my $del(@files)
    {
     unlink $del;
    }
```

**Optimized solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = grep {-f} glob("*.xml");
my @files1 = grep {-f} glob("*.html");
open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
print F6 "FileName\tError Instance\tOutput\n";
foreach my $f (@files)
 {
my $xml_list = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh,'<',"$f" or die "Cannot open file: $f";
  <$fh>;
};

my $xml_list1 = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh,'<',"abc.html" or die "Cannot open file: $f";
  <$fh>;
};


print $xml_list1."\n";

while($xml_list =~ m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
{
        my $full=$1;
        my $name=$2;
        #print F6 $f."\t".$full."\n";       
if($full =~ m/(<givenNames>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/givenNames>\s*<familyName>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/familyName>\s*(.*?))/isg)
        {
        my $fg=$1;
        my $gname=$2;
        my $fname=$3;
        #print F6 $f."\t".$gname."\t".$fname."\n";
        }
     }
while($xml_list1 =~ m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)"\s+SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/isg)        
    {
    my $hfull= $1;
    print F6 $f . "\n";   #.$hfull."\n";
    }

}
foreach my $del(@files)
{
  unlink $del;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@flora : Try this code . I was busy with other work so couldn't reply soon. Now this code will generate following output :

**Input File:(sample.xml)**

```
<creators> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="01"> 
<personName><givenNames>Kazumitsu</givenNames><familyName>Sugiura</familyName></personName>
</creator> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="02"> 
<personName><givenNames>Yoshinao</givenNames><familyName>Muro</familyName></personName>
</cre??ator> 
<creator affiliationRef="#01" creatorRole="author" xml:id="03"> 
<personName><givenNames>Masashi</givenNames><familyName>Akiyama</familyName></personName> 
</creator>
</creators>
```

**InputFile(abc.html):**

```
<P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA, Yoshinao Muro, and Masashi Akiyama</I></FONT></P>
```

**Output:**

```
FileName    MatchedString   Output
Matched Sugiura(sample.xml)->SUGIURA(abc.html)
Matched Muro(sample.xml)->Muro(abc.html)
Matched Akiyama(sample.xml)->Akiyama(abc.html)
```

**Code:**

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Cwd;
    use File::Copy;
    use File::Basename;

    my $path1=getcwd;
    #print $path1;
    opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
    my @out = grep(/\.(xml)$/,readdir(INP));
    closedir INP;
    opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
    my @out1 = grep(/\.(html)$/,readdir(INP));
    #print @out1;
    closedir INP;


    foreach my $final(@out)
    {
     my $filetobecopied = "Input\/".$final;
     my $newfile = $final;

     copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    }

    foreach my $final1(@out1)
    {
     my $filetobecopied1 = "Input\/".$final1;
     my $newfile1 = $final1;
     #print $final1;
     copy($filetobecopied1, $newfile1) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    }

    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files = grep /(.*?)\.(xml)$/,(readdir DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files1 = grep /(.*?)\.(html)$/,(readdir DIR);        
    closedir DIR;
    #print @files1;

    open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
    print F6 "FileName\tMatchedString\tOutput\n";

    # open(F2,"<F2>");
    # my $xml_list1="abc.html";
    # my $data1=join("",<F1>);
    # my $xml_list2=$xml_list1;

    foreach my $f (@files)
     {   


    open(F1, "<$path1\/Input\/$f") or die "Cannot open file: $f - $!";
    my $data=join("", <F1>);
    close F1;
    my $xml_list=$data;    
    #print $xml_list;
   foreach my $f1 (@files1)
    {
         my @fname=(); 
         my @hfull=();
        print $f1 . "\n";
    open(F2, "<$path1\/Input\/$f1") or die "Cannot open file: $f1 - $!";
    my $data1=join("", <F2>);
    close F2;
    my $xml_list1=$data1;
    #print $xml_list1;
    while($xml_list =~ m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
    {
            my $full=$1;
            #print $full . "\n";
    if($full =~ m/(<givenNames>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/givenNames>\s*<familyName>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/familyName>\s*(.*?))/isg)
            { 
              push(@fname,$3);
                 }

         }
    while($xml_list1 =~ m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)" SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/isg)        
        {
           push(@hfull,$4);
       }

    foreach my $a (@fname)
      {
        foreach my $b (@hfull)
           { 
            #print $b . "\n";
              if($b =~ m/$a/isg)
                 {     
                    my $line  = substr($b,index(lc($b),lc($a)),length($a));
                      print F6 "Matched $a($f)\->$line($f1)\n";
                      }   
               }
         }      
      }     
    }       
   foreach my $del(@files)
    {
     unlink $del;
    }
```

**Optimized code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Cwd;
    use File::Copy;
    use File::Basename;

    my $path1=getcwd;
    #print $path1;
    #opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
    #my @out = grep(/\.(xml)$/,readdir(INP));
    #closedir INP;
    #opendir(INP, "$path1\/Input");
    #my @out1 = grep(/\.(html)$/,readdir(INP));
    #print @out1;
    #closedir INP;


    #foreach my $final(@out)
    #{
    #my $filetobecopied = "Input\/".$final;
    # my $newfile = $final;

     #copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    #}

    #foreach my $final1(@out1)
    #{
    # my $filetobecopied1 = "Input\/".$final1;
    # my $newfile1 = $final1;
     #print $final1;
    # copy($filetobecopied1, $newfile1) or die "File cannot be copied.";
    #}

    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files = grep /(.*?)\.(xml)$/,(readdir DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    opendir DIR, $path1 or die "cant open dir";
    my @files1 = grep /(.*?)\.(html)$/,(readdir DIR);        
    closedir DIR;
    #print @files1;

    open(F6, ">Ref.txt");
    print F6 "FileName\tMatchedString\tOutput\n";

    # open(F2,"<F2>");
    # my $xml_list1="abc.html";
    # my $data1=join("",<F1>);
    # my $xml_list2=$xml_list1;

    foreach my $f (@files)
     {   


    open(F1, "<$path1\/$f") or die "Cannot open file: $f - $!";
    my $data=join("", <F1>);
    close F1;
    my $xml_list=$data;    
    #print $xml_list;
   foreach my $f1 (@files1)
    {
         my @fname=(); 
         my @hfull=();
        print $f1 . "\n";
    open(F2, "<$path1\/$f1") or die "Cannot open file: $f1 - $!";
    my $data1=join("", <F2>);
    close F2;
    my $xml_list1=$data1;
    #print $xml_list1;
    while($xml_list =~ m/(<personName>(.*?)<\/personName>)/isg)
    {
            my $full=$1;
            #print $full . "\n";
    if($full =~ m/(<givenNames>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/givenNames>\s*<familyName>\s*(\w+)\s*<\/familyName>\s*(.*?))/isg)
            { 
              push(@fname,$3);
                 }

         }
    while($xml_list1 =~ m/(<p><FONT FACE="(.*?)" SIZE="(\d+)"><I>(.*?)<\/I><\/FONT><\/p>)/isg)        
        {
           push(@hfull,$4);
       }

    foreach my $a (@fname)
      {
        foreach my $b (@hfull)
           { 
            #print $b . "\n";
              if($b =~ m/$a/isg)
                 {     
                    my $line  = substr($b,index(lc($b),lc($a)),length($a));
                      print F6 "Matched $a($f)\->$line($f1)\n";
                      }   
               }
         }      
      }     
    }       
   #foreach my $del(@files)
    #{
    # unlink $del;
    #}
```

Comment: it shows an error for the new variable i.e:                                        D:\>match.pl
Global symbol "@fname" requires explicit package name at D:\match.pl line 55.
Global symbol "@hfull" requires explicit package name at D:\match.pl line 60.
Global symbol "@fname" requires explicit package name at D:\match.pl line 63.
Global symbol "@hfull" requires explicit package name at D:\match.pl line 65.
Execution of D:\match.pl aborted due to compilation errors.           Can we keep the .html file name varying because then everytime the user needs to keep it as abc only. Please help me

Comment: Did you copy the entire code of mine . I have declared the variables @ fname and @ hfull in the code. If you did not copy the entire code then it will show an error. I will modify the code for html file and get back to you.

Comment: @flora: I have modified the code . Copy the entire code and run the program . Now it has work.

Comment: @flora : I just wanted to know why you want to copy the files into the folder Input and then again delete the files from the current directory . Why don't you directly put all the files(xml and html) in the current directory and delete others . I am placing the optimized code by running the files from $path1 . Please check

Comment: thanks for sharing the code...sorry for the delay.. The optimized code compares name from xml with the entire html file.Trying to match only one name from xml with that in html i.e if its "ABC" in xml I want to match it only with "ABC"(case insensitive) in html file and not with the entire file.

Comment: But previously you asked me to get the case sensitive matches. So you mean to say if "ABC" in xml and "ABC" in html or "abc" in xml and "abc" in html matches then you have to print the output . Am i right ?

Comment: I mean if its Abc in xml and aBc in HTML it should match. It matches Abc from xml with each and every name enclosed in particular tag in html and the same enclosed in regex to find that particular tag. I need to print only Abc from xml with aBc from HTML.

Comment: @flora : So you mean to say if there is an html file like this <P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA, Yoshinao Muro, and Masashi Akiyama</I></FONT></P> then the output will be nothing but if the hmtl file is like this <P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA</I></FONT></P> then it should match SUGIURA in html with sugiura in xml file . Am i going correct ?

Comment: my HTML file has all tags this way only i.e <P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA, Yoshinao Muro, and Masashi Akiyama</I></FONT></P> and I need to match Kazumitsu SUGIURA from xml file with ONLY this particular part from html file i.e Kazumitsu SUGIURA and not with the other <P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>.....</I></FONT></P> tags.

Comment: @flora : You mean to say that pattern you want to match is fixed i.e. Pattern that need to be matched from xml and html  is only Kazumitsu SUGIURA ?

Comment: I took kazumitsu sugiura as an example.. i need to match Yoshinao Muro,Masashi Akiyama and lot more........ How to go about to find just the pattern of interest from both files?

Comment: So you want one pattern to be passed as an argument to the program and this pattern need to check in xml and html files . If this matches then you want to print the xml and html filenames with the pattern .Am i going correct ?

Comment: YES...the pattern may differ it can be author name, place name etc... and that pattern(xml) should match with the pattern present in html as an output

Comment: Still not clear .. Where are this authornames , placenames present in the xml file. I can see only <PersonNames> , <givenNames> , <familyNames> present in the xml file . So be specific otherwise we cannot solve the issue?

Comment: as placed in the input file(sample.xml) and (abc.html)
I need to match <givenNames>Kazumitsu</givenNames><familyName>Sugiura</familyName> from xml with <P><FONT FACE="hello" SIZE="14"><I>Kazumitsu SUGIURA, Yoshinao Muro, and Masashi Akiyama</I></FONT></P> from html... I need to match each <givenname>and <familyname> with that present in<P><I>tag